# How to disable local network browsing?

Tags: networking

Unlike many posters here, I would actually like to ***disable*** the ability to browse local network shares and hosts on the local network. ***through the file manager***. In other words, when you click on "network" in the file manager, nautilus, or whatever, I don't want to see anything. This used to be something I had to enable in years past, now it is default.

I've uninstalled network-manager, avahi and samba+samba-common and I still see hosts when I click on the network.

How do I disable this?

A clarification: users need internet access, ok? But I don't want them to be able to view other devices and computers on the local area network. In Windows 7, I could choose "public network", done. This disables file and print sharing as well as the ability to discover other computers in the network 'hood, as it were. Many nixes do not have this enabled by default. How do I disable this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you using a router?

Comment: @Mitch -- I'm not sure what you mean. There is a router, IPS, switches ...etc. This is an enterprise network. Because this computer is in a slightly vulnerable physical location I simply want to make it a bit more difficult to *easily* see who else is on the network (LAN), or domain. An isolated network segment would help this situation of course. But for now, I *want* the problem this poster has:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/305887/network-devices-not-appearing?rq=1 --- no it's not fool-proof, but it can be done, it used to be default for certain nixes, BSDs ...etc. So how?

Comment: Maybe you want to disable gvfs.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) (firewall) is what you need.

Try:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

The default config will deny all incoming connections and allow all outgoing connections.

If you love GUI, you can use the GUI version: [Gufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw).

Comment: This sounds promising, I'll give this a shot. Strange though that there isn't a simple solution …not involving disabling interfaces as Radu seems hellbent on. I remember setting up linux before and not being able to browse the network in nautilus or any file manager.